# How can I see cache hits. force.com site with PKB and url rewriter

Tags: force.com-sites, caching, cache

We are hitting > 1million page views a month so I began looking at ways to reduce it. I found that we had explicitly set cache=false on the 3 main pages. A month ago I set this to cache=true with a limit of 900.
I set this on 3 pages: Active Site Home Page, Site Template, our contact form page.

We have installed the site usage dashboards from the appExchange and I'm not seeing any hits on the cache (assuming they would show as 'Cache Page Views' under usage type?)

1.Should I see data under that usage type?

Using chrome devTools I can see the pages are being cached locally.

- This in a production org.
- The site has no login allowed.
- We have PKB2 installed.
- We have a rewriter class.
- We have many different urls hosted from the one site. Each site representing a different brand or language.
- ONE of these urls is SSL enabled.

2.Does anyone have experince with caching and pkb2?

Answer (score 0):

Found out from Salesforce support that cache hits reporting in salesforce is only for static resources. That's why I wasn't seeing any hits.